# Time to word converter

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I was wondering if I could make an app in which time is display in words instead of conventional numbers. Do you think that there is any package for dart to convert time or numbers to words?

For example
1:30 AM will be One : Thirty AM

Thanks for reading this question. Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of available package to convert from number to words example

package: https://pub.dev/packages/number_to_words

```
import 'package:number_to_words/number_to_words.dart';

main(){
  String input = '1:30 AM';
  var s1 = input.split(':');
  var s2 = s1[1].split(' ');
  String hour = s1[0];
  String minute = s2[0];
  String hourWord = NumberToWord().convert('en-in',int.parse(hour));
  String minuteWord = NumberToWord().convert('en-in',int.parse(minute));
  print('$hourWord:$minuteWork ${s2[1]}');
}
```